# Postfix issue on Ubuntu (Amazon EC2): can not send email after a few success

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, postfix

I installed Posifx on Ubuntu 18.4 LT on an amazon EC2 box. After installation and configuration, I was able to send out two emails to my hotmail and another email account. I do received them. However, I can not send any email any more. I check the /var/log/mail.log. It shows the "connection timed out" Error on these sending attempt.

I am confused why I was able to send but later can not. One thing I am not sure, when configuring the /etc/hosts, I did not use a real FQDN, I just give something like hostname.xxx.com because I can not find FQDN on my amazon EC2 box. Does that cause the problem.

I need to send email out when my application status is changed. Does anyone have experience on sending email from Amazon EC2 box?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sign up and configure server to use a SMTP relay service.

Example: https://www.smtp2go.com/

Comment: I tried gmail relay. It works most time. But sometime I got "connect to smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c08::6c]:587: Network is unreachable". Do you know why?

Comment: Does it always have an IPv6 address?